# Is there React Three Fiber (R3F) analogue in Vue?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, three.js

I am currently learning three.js and i wonder if there something like React Three Fiber, but in Vue?
I dont want to learn another framework in order to work with this tool.

I googled about it, but found only github chinese repo which doesnt contain that i need

Comment: It's a risk to invest into low-profile lib like the one is shown in the answer, exactly because you can be left with unmaintained piece of code any moment. The use of vanilla lib with a framework of your choice is a safer strategy in such case

Comment: @EstusFlask OP is clearly looking for a baked-in solution and probably following Bruno Simon's course. So it's either "do it vanilla" or use those smaller ones indeed. Nuxt backing it up may help for sure but it will never be as big as R3F for sure. Any OSS library can die tomorrow. The one suggested may be totally nice as a starter, for simple use-cases. Adding a bit of ThreeJS vanilla on top of it also provides nice results. I've achieved several 3D things doing just that already. For something more complex, vanilla ThreeJS is still the way to go anyway.

Comment: Even using ThreeJS itself, is a risk somewhat considering the fact that it's far from being able as much things as WebGL allows you to do. A middle-ground is always a nice start. For more in-depth work, OP will figure it out down the road. 3D is shinning at best in Unity and not that easy to work with in a State based JS framework ecosystem overall, so all the existing solutions nowadays are by default sub-par. Shorter cartesian answer could be: "no, there is nothing similar".

Comment: @kissu Yes, I agree. Would be interested to check https://github.com/Tresjs once it's stable. Based on my own experience, I'd go with a dep by https://github.com/pmndrs because they do a good work and don't ditch their libs afaik. Would think twice for smaller ones that aren't a write-and-forget thing, and something like 3js wrapper certainly needs a constant attention

Comment: @EstusFlask pmndrs is equivalent to [VueUse](https://vueuse.org/) but for Vue, which is maintained by Nuxt core team members (as said in my answer). Which is smaller for sure, but still the best equivalent in a Vue ecosystem. And Tres will probably get an integration there once ready and stable as discussed last time on Discord with one Nuxt employee. It's always a delicate topic and you never know when something will stop. Knowing a bit the maintainers + project helps for sure.

Comment: Three.js itself is quite risky since it has never been made into a stable version. The best thing is to fork your own three.js version and maintain that.

Answer (score 1):

There is [TroisJS](https://github.com/troisjs/trois), it's not heavily maintained unfortunately.

---

As an alternative, here is a nice boilerplate: https://github.com/alvarosabu/modern-three

---

My friend is also working on maintaining [this library](https://github.com/Tresjs/tres), that he want to modernize and keep updated in the long run. He will receive some help from the Nuxt team + is quite dedicated to 3D so it may be worth giving it a try.
The repo is currently private, but you can join [his Discord](https://discord.gg/chdRYfDq) and share this Stackoverflow question (he knows me) to get a VIP invite.

PS: he will make it public in a near future, but you can already have a preview + start playing with it while you're learning ThreeJS.